# Spring Boot API Gateway giving error like Load balancer not found for microservice

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, api-gateway

I am new in spring boot application with eureka. I am getting above exception while using API Gateway with eureka and docker for following configuration.

**API-Gateway's Bootstrap.yml**

```
spring:
  profiles: docker-development-cloud
  application:
    name: api-gateway
zuul:
  routes:
    user:
      path: /api/user**
      service-id: usermicroservice
    user1:
      path: /api/user/**
      service-id: usermicroservice
    web-portal: /**
host:
    connect-timeout-millis: 1000000
    socket-timeout-millis: 90000
hystrix:
  command.default.execution.isolation.strategy: THREAD
  command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 90000
  command.default.execution.timeout.enabled: false
  command.default.fallback.enabled: false
  threadpool.default.coreSize: 20
user:
  ribbon:
    ReadTimeout: 90000
    ConnectTimeout: 90000
user1:
  ribbon:
    ReadTimeout: 90000
    ConnectTimeout: 90000
web-portal:
  ribbon:
    ReadTimeout: 90000
    ConnectTimeout: 90000
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
      ##defaultZone: http://eureka-server:8761/eureka/
    registry-fetch-interval-seconds: 5000
  instance:
    hostname: api-gateway
    prefer-ip-address: false
    lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds: 5000
    lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds: 5000
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
{
    "services": {
        "api-gateway": {
            "environment": {
                "JAVA_OPTS": "-Xms256m -Xmx512m",
                "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE": "docker-development-cloud",
                "build": {
                    "context": "../../",
                    "dockerfile": "api-gateway/src/main/dockerDevelopBuildRelease/Dockerfile",
                    "ports": [
                        "8763:8763"
                    ],
                    "restart": "always",
                    "networks": [
                        "cloud"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "image": "jci_bts_tms_common_services/api-gateway:develop",
            "mem_limit": "1024M"
        },
        "web-portal": {
            "environment": {
                "JAVA_OPTS": "-Xms256m -Xmx512m",
                "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE": "docker-development-cloud"
            },
            "build": {
                "dockerfile": "web-portal/src/main/dockerDevelopBuildRelease/Dockerfile",
                "context": "../../"
            },
            "mem_limit": "1024M",
            "image": "web-portal:develop",
            "networks": [
                "cloud"
            ],
            "restart": "always",
            "ports": [
                "8764:8764"
            ]
        },
        "ms-user": {
            "environment": {
                "JAVA_OPTS": "-Xms256m -Xmx512m",
                "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE": "docker-development-cloud"
            },
            "build": {
                "dockerfile": "ms-user/src/main/dockerDevelopBuildRelease/Dockerfile",
                "context": "../../"
            },
            "mem_limit": "1024M",
            "image": "ms-user:develop",
            "networks": [
                "cloud"
            ],
            "restart": "always",
            "ports": [
                "9004:9004"
            ]
        }
    },
    "version": "2",
    "networks": {
        "cloud": {
            "driver": "bridge"
        }
    }
}
```

**web-portal's bootstrap.yml**

```
{
  "spring": {
    "application": {
      "name": "web-portal"
    }, 
    "logging": {
      "file": "logs/web-portal.log", 
      "level": {
        "org.springframework.web": "INFO", 
        "com.***.portal": "DEBUG", 
        "org.springframework.security": "INFO"
      }
    }, 
    "profiles": "docker-development-cloud", 
    "eureka": {
      "instance": {
        "hostname": "web-portal", 
        "prefer-ip-address": true, 
        "lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds": 5000, 
        "lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds": 5000
      }, 
      "client": { 
        "fetch-registry": true, 
        "enabled": true, 
        "eureka-service-url-poll-interval-seconds": 5000, 
        "register-with-eureka": true, 
        "serviceUrl": {
          "defaultZone": "http://eureka-server:8761/eureka/"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**User's bootstrap.yml**

```
spring:
  profiles: docker-development-cloud
  application:
    name: plantmicroservice
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://eureka-server:8761/eureka/
    registry-fetch-interval-seconds: 5000
  instance:
    hostname: usermicroservice
    prefer-ip-address: true
    lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds: 5000
    lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds: 5000
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: INFO
    org.springframework.web: INFO
    com.***.portal: DEBUG
  file: logs/ms-contract.log
```

With this Configuration I am getting exception as **Load balancer does not found for micro-service: web-portal.** Suggest some solution for resolving this issue, I searched every where but I am not getting solution.
Stack trace of above exception is :

```
2017-07-17 10:21:50.463  WARN 1 --- [nio-8763-exec-4] o.s.c.n.z.filters.post.SendErrorFilter   : Error during filtering

com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.handleException(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:183) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:158) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:106) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:112) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar!/:1.3.0]
        at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:193) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar!/:1.3.0]
        at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:157) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar!/:1.3.0]
        at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:118) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar!/:1.3.0]
        at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar!/:1.3.0]
        at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar!/:1.3.0]
        at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar!/:1.3.0]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:157) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequest(ZuulController.java:44) [spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: usermicroservice
        at com.netflix.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerContext.getServerFromLoadBalancer(LoadBalancerContext.java:483) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.2.jar!/:2.2.2]
        at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:184) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.2.jar!/:2.2.2]
        at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:180) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.2.jar!/:2.2.2]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:94) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:42) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber$1.call(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:127) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.enqueue(TrampolineScheduler.java:73) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.schedule(TrampolineScheduler.java:52) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:79) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:45) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$WeakSingleProducer.request(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:276) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:209) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:138) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:129) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10307) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10274) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:445) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.single(BlockingObservable.java:342) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:117) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.2.jar!/:2.2.2]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.support.AbstractRibbonCommand.run(AbstractRibbonCommand.java:105) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.support.AbstractRibbonCommand.run(AbstractRibbonCommand.java:43) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:302) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
        at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:298) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10307) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10274) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.BlockingOperatorToFuture.toFuture(BlockingOperatorToFuture.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.toFuture(BlockingObservable.java:412) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
        at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.queue(HystrixCommand.java:378) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
        at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.execute(HystrixCommand.java:344) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:152) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        ... 67 common frames omitted
```